# without looking in config.txt, how can I see my start_x setting?

Tags: raspicam

Basically, I'd like to verify if the camera is getting enabled. I've grepped around on `dmesg` and `/var/log` and `lsmod`, and have googled, and I have failed so far.

I went to a machine where I know the camera is working and don't see an entry in lsmod for v4l, which was one hunch.

Comment: run `vcgencmd get_camera` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the camera status using `vcgencmd get_camera` on the command line.

It will show if the camera is enabled / supported and if it is connected.

```
pi@raspi05:$ vcgencmd get_camera
supported=1 detected=0
```

Comment: also worth noting, the GPU memory split is available with `vcgencmd get_mem gpu`.